# Getting Error while Adding the Spartacus Schematics

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I was trying to integrate Spartacus with the SAP Commerce cloud.
i was following a video in youtube, PFB the steps

1. ng new spartacusdemostore --styles=scss
2. ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest

But while executing the 2nd step, i am getting the below error. Can anyone help me on this.

*require() of ES Module C:\Hybris\SpartacusDemo\spartacusdemostore\node_modules@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Hybris\SpartacusDemo\spartacusdemostore\node_modules@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.*

[Please find the Error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XWat.png)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is what i found in the Official docs for the Spartacus. I believe this means they already fixed it. But still i am facing this issue. ----

When running ng add @spartacus/schematics in a fresh app, the error occurs: require() of ES Module <path-to-app>/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.mjs not supported. Instead change the require of <path-to-app>/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Proposed fix: in our schematics change the import of @angular/compiler to a dynamic import (PR #15273)

Answer (score 0):

As of writing, the latest schematics is tagged with `4.3.4`, which will pull all packages for Spartacus which you opted in for during the schematics interaction for the specified version.

As stated in the official docs for Spartacus, it mentions that any Spartacus version for 4.x needs to use Angular 12. Moreover, as you pointed out, PR #15273 was a change to adhere to Angular 13, which still has not been released as it will be shipped with 5.x in the future.

All in all, please downgrade your Angular version to Angular 12 before running schematics again

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, i tried downgrading angular to even 9 but it was breaking with some other errors, but today after installing Angular 12 - it worked.....